# Write info in variables without create a file

Tags: bash

I have some script on bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time_event="`date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M:%S`"
current_day="`date +%Y%m%d`"
event="start_job"

src='hdfs://table1/'
dst='hdfs://table2/'

hadoop distcp -bandwidth 256 -m 50 -delete -update -strategy dynamic $src $dst &> log.txt

status=($?)

link=$(grep -oP "The url to track the job: \K[^']+" log.txt)
job=$(grep -oP "Submitting tokens for job: \K[^']+" log.txt)

hive -e "insert into table <table> partition (day) select '$src' as source_path, '$dst' as target_path, '$time_event' as time_event, '$event' as event, '$status' as status, '$link' as url_job, '$job' as url_pipeline, $current_day as day;"
```

How can I do the same without write info in file and read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store the result in a variable via [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), like you are already doing for `link` and `job`.

Also make sure to quote your parameters when expanding, otherwise you might run into issues later on (word splitting, wildcard expansion, [etc.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells))

```
log="$(hadoop distcp -bandwidth 256 -m 50 -delete -update -strategy dynamic "$src" "$dst" 2>&1)"

link=$(printf '%s\n' "$log" | grep -oP "The url to track the job: \K[^']+")
job=$(printf '%s\n' "$log" | grep -oP "Submitting tokens for job: \K[^']+")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get all you need at once with `read` and `awk`:

```
read -r link job < <(
    hadoop distcp -bandwidth... | awk '
    /The url to track the job:/{link=$2}
    /Submitting tokens for job:/{job=$2}
    END{print link, job}'
)
```

Comment: Only if link does not contain any whitespace characters

Comment: A link cannot contain white-spaces unless those are percent-encoded like '%20'